# $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t$ is Convergent

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Define $$I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|}{\frac{1}{4}+t^2} \mathrm{d}t.$$ Balazard, Saias and Yor showed that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the statement that $I=0$.

I want to prove that I is convergent.

My try:-

$$\zeta(s)= s\int_1^\infty \frac{1-x+[x]}{x^{s+1}}dx +\frac{1}{s-1}, \Re(s)>0$$

So $$\mid \zeta(1/2+it)|\leq 2\sqrt{1/4+t^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/4+t^2}}$$

$$\mid \zeta(1/2+it)|\leq \frac{2(1/4+t^2)+1}{\sqrt{1/4+t^2}}$$

$$log \mid \zeta(1/2+it)\mid \leq log(\frac{3/2+t^2}{\sqrt{1/4+t^2}})$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{log \mid \zeta(1/2+it)\mid}{1/4+t^2}dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{log(\frac{3/2+t^2}{\sqrt{1/4+t^2}})}{1/4+t^2}dt$$
Since $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ log (1/4+t^2)}{1/4+t^2}=0$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{log \mid \zeta(1/2+it)\mid}{1/4+t^2}dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{log({3/2+t^2})}{1/4+t^2}dt$$

The last integral converges  [see this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%ABlog%28%281.5%2Bt%5E2%29%29+%2F%280.25%2Bt%5E2%29dt+t%3D0+to+infinity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that the OP proof above actually shows that $I$ cannot be $\infty$ but it doesn't show that $I$ converges or it is not $-\infty$ since $I$ is an oscillating integral with $\log |\zeta|=-\infty$ infinitely many times on the critical line of course.

From general results about Hardy spaces and some changes of variable, it actually follows immediately that $I$ is finite but much more is known, namely that

$0 \le I \le 0.146$

(and much tighter bounds can be easily found by better numerics) as from the results of [Balazard, Saias and Yor](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870898917972?via%3Dihub) we know that:

$I=2\pi \sum_{\Re \rho >1/2}\log \frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|}=\pi \sum_{\Re \rho >1/2}\log \frac{|\rho|^2}{|1-\rho|^2}$

But now if $\rho=\sigma+it, \frac{|\rho|^2}{|1-\rho|^2}=\frac{\sigma^2+t^2}{(1-\sigma)^2+t^2}=1+\frac{\sigma^2-(1-\sigma)^2}{(1-\sigma)^2+t^2}$, so we have

$ 1 < \frac{|\rho|^2}{|1-\rho|^2} < 1+\frac{1}{(1-\sigma)^2+t^2}$ whenever $\sigma >1/2$ hence $0 < \log \frac{|\rho|^2}{|1-\rho|^2} < \frac{1}{(1-\sigma)^2+t^2}=\frac{1}{|1-\rho|^2}$

But now it is well known (see [Broughan, Equivalents if The Riemann Hypothesis, vol 1, page 35](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/equivalents-of-the-riemann-hypothesis/6900C0A3B7B2ABBCE3EB285641F95A30)) that: $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2} \le  .046191441$, where the sum is taken on all the non-trivial zeroes of zeta.

Since either $I=0$ if RH is true, or $0 <I < \pi \sum_{\Re \rho <1/2}\frac{1}{|1-\rho|^2}< \pi \times .046191441=0.145...$ if RH is false and the sum is non-void, we immediately see the claimed result; using that all the zeroes up to some huge $t$ are known to be on the critical line so not in the sum above, we can probably reduce the estimate of $I$ to a ridiculously low nonnegative number, showing the tightness of the equivalence.

Comment: Can you please give me a reference which shows that $  I \geq 0?$

Comment: $I$ is either a void sum or a sum of positive numbers from the Balazard et others result since $\frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|}>1$ whenever $\Re \rho >1/2$ hence $\log \frac{|\rho|}{|1-\rho|} >0$ then

Comment: How is it a void sum?

Comment: if RH is true then $I$ is a void sum (hence zero) since there are no zeroes with $\Re \rho >1/2$; this is why the integral zero is equivalent to RH

Comment: Ok I see . Thank you for your effort. I am giving you a check mark. Awesome answer sir.

Comment: Can you provide me a reference for finding an upper bound for $$\prod_{\rho}\frac{1}{\mid \rho\mid^2}$$?

Comment: the product is trivially zero if you take it on all the zeroes of RH since the generic term converges to zero; the sum is bounded by some small constant as per Broughan

Comment: I am not exactly on the critical line. I am somewhere in the critical strip. Then i want an upper bound.

Comment: Upper bound for $$\prod _{0<\Re(\rho)<1}\frac{1}{\mid \rho \mid ^2}?$$

Comment: not sure of the question - the product diverges to zero

Comment: Reference please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: How is it divergent?

Comment: an infinite product that "converges" to zero is called divergent to zero for various reasons (essentially $0$ has bad multiplicative behavior), so the terminology can be a bit misleading but it is customary

Comment: I know this. But how is it divergent? Proof please?

Comment: not sure of the question - $|\rho| \to \infty$ hence $1/|\rho| \to 0$ and any product $\Pi |a_n|, |a_n| \to 0$ diverges trivially to zero as $|a_n| \le 1/2, n \ge N$ so $0 \le P_k \le C/2^{k-N}, k \ge N$ hence $P_k \to 0$

Comment: What If $ I<0?$. Will it imply RH?

Comment: $I$ cannot be negative, it is either zero or positive

Comment: Thanks a ton. You are very helpful.

Comment: so if I$\leq 0$ then RH is true?